# Which parts part of CeFi UX are still missing in DeFi and holding back adoption?

Tags: defi, user-experience, adoption

Often in articles about cryptocurrency adoption I see it underlined how the existing DeFi protocols and related frontends are highly technical and far off the immediate and simplistic user experience of CeFi people are used to.
Yet considering the huge capital influx in DeFi, I am sure web3 companies are perfectly capable of creating top notch websites and smart contracts to match usability requirements. Therefore, wallet integration seems to have improved a lot with MetaMask paving the way for quick and easy onboarding.
What are all those articles pointing to, what is still missing in DeFi to make adoption seamless and widespread from a technical point of view?

Comment: It has improved but managing a private keys is still a hard obstacle to overcome. Many people use services like Coinbase, Binance, Huobi, etc. because the username and password mechanism is something they use and are familiar with.